# Typescript condition with strings in function always return false

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a weird error in a typescript condition in a function. There is my current code. My params came from outside:

```
  getLevel(validation: string, status: string): string {
    let card = "";

    if (validation == "A") {
      if (!status) {
        card = "card-success";
      } else {
        switch (status) {
          case "S":
            // console.log("case s");
            card = "card-success";
            break;
          case "C":
          case "U":
          case "V":
            // console.log("case cuv");
            card = "card-low";
            break;
          default:
            // console.log("case default");
            card = "card-success";
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    return card;
  }
```

For test I tried this :

```
  getLevel(validation2: string, status2: string): string {
    let card = "";
    const validation = "A"; // for test purpose
    const status = "U"; // for test purpose
    if (status == status2) { // for test purpose
      console.log("aeae"); // not working
    }

    console.log(status); //display U
    console.log(status2); // display U
    console.log(typeof status); //display string
    console.log(typeof status2); // display string

    if (validation == "A") {
      switch (status) {
        case "S":
          console.log("case s");
          card = "card-success";
          break;
        case "C":
        case "U":
        case "V":
          console.log("case cuv");
          card = "card-low";  // should display this one and works with variables defined within the function
          break;
        default:
          console.log("case default"); // display this one with data from function args
          card = "card-success";
          break;
      }
    }
    return card;
  }
```

So when I try with variable in my code it works but not with my params. I also tried with a simple if statement but it doesn't work either.
There is my debugger screenshot

[image]

Comment: did you try ```===``` ?

Comment: `===` shouldn't make a difference, because `==` compare value and `===` only add an additional type check

Comment: I already tried and it makes no difference, moreover the switch case does not work as wanted neither

Comment: What's the problem exactly? do you mean the `Type '"S"' is not comparable to type '"U"'.(2678)`?

Comment: Yes exactly (my name si Mady :), too many Madys in here). I tried to cast status but nothing changes

Comment: What does the call look like that you say doesn't work?

Comment: @DaveG look at the comments in my code. I do not pass the correct case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it was not working:

I check my parameters length and there was a space after the strings.

```
status.length // 2
```

So I add a .trim() to my variable

```
const trimedStatus = status.trim();
```

I wonder why I didn't see it in the Google console.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `const status = "U"`. if you hover over `status` in your IDE, it says that the type of `status` is `"U"`. it means that the `status` variable can only be `"U"`, no other characters or strings. if you want to manually say to typescript that status shouldn't be of type `"U"`, you can say:

```
const status : string = "U"
```

Or in a more logical way, declare your `status` variable with `let` so typescript knows that there's the possibility that you may change the value of `status` variable down the line.

```
let status = "U"


function getLevel(validation2: string, status2: string): string {
    let card = "";
    const validation = "A";
    let status = "U";
    if (status == status2) {
      console.log("aeae"); // not working
    }

    console.log(status); //display U
    console.log(status2); // display U
    console.log(typeof status); //display string
    console.log(typeof status2); // display string

    if (validation == "A") {
      switch (status) {
        case "S":
          console.log("case s");
          card = "card-success";
          break;
        case "C":
        case "U":
        case "V":
          console.log("case cuv");
          card = "card-low";  // should display this one and works with variables defined within the function
          break;
        default:
          console.log("case default"); // display this one with data from function args
          card = "card-success";
          break;
      }
    }
    return card;
  }
```

[Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATBmFcDsGMBcEsD2lgHMCmsAy6Bu6AbAClwEMD4ATUhZAJgC5gBnWAJ3klQBoXYbwzRnw5cAlE1ajUwAN4AoECAKZg0Um0rAAvMABEegNyKl0ZK2BkK1Wil16AgkZPLVrAcx36Aqs6XB4UGAid1hBHV1QwToxORdTc0QVADoCRFQiPVJ0bL0xQ2AAekLgSERYYAB3RDYAa05UeIBfeXizSGYk9FT0kP4w5nyiwsp4ZgAHAlIAT2BvNsSUtIyooSHi4FGJqdn5-3bOpd7YafH0RCDV9ZGxyZmRBoWOrp6Mk7OLvg8Ygo2tu9mUke8UCwSsVBoSDs9icsQU-hAzEq8Fg0AAFsErnEEaZSMx0PoAMp6BjxHEHF7LTLqfEsPLGHH7DRaezqTQAWmY4Gg0HQzGYfkZIAARmwcrUGYyaQS9ABhElk3G0vS%20UlC6X6ABqCqFIApRwyeg10HAuHpiqZmi8RuZ7LSlSMIA2zDRiHABC0-x2wFgaLGwGQBNIkC01TqnmRvssGngpGFKk8lHQoE46FDKL9KF9BIgMFsFqUovFkpxSdApHdsDVuv13SpNtpZYrBFg9OGm1u3t9-sDVQzmxopDAbEQAFswFA4FDgBpUMwC3rmda2ZROdzefzBUKi6QJYqWv4D0oxWE2CgV5KmkA)

Comment: It does no wort i update my question, those variables on top was only for test purpose

Comment: @DanM.CISSOKHO I'm confused. everything is working as expected. isn't your problem because of missed `break` statements? I removed all the lines you'd added for testing purpose, here's the playground link: https://b2n.ir/196690.  please reproduce your issue in a playground.

Comment: I can't, i already test with a playground everything seems to be fine, that's why I post the screenshot. With data within my function, everything is ok but not with the function parameters

Answer (score 0):

I just copied and pasted the original getLevel() method into a test project and called it and it worked fine:

```
    test() {
    console.log(this.getLevel("A", null));
    console.log(this.getLevel("A", "S"));
    console.log(this.getLevel("A", "C"));
    console.log(this.getLevel("A", "U"));
    console.log(this.getLevel("A", "X"));
    console.log(this.getLevel("A", "UNKNOWN"));
}
```

Output was what I would expect:

```
card-success
card-success
card-low
card-low
card-success
card-success
```

You must have an error in your calls.

Comment: If you look at my console snapshot, there is no errors with my parameters. It's working for me too in a playground

Comment: @DanM.CISSOKHO this isn't a playground with set values for the parameters, this is with calls to getLevel().  I'm calling your original method and it's working.  So it works fine with parameters.  You must have an error in your calls with the parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your variable declaration once. I have reproduced the working example.

You were missing **status2** variable declaration.

```js
function getLevel(validation, status) {
    let card = "";
    if (validation == status) { // for test purpose
      console.log("aeae"); // not working
    }

    if (validation == "A") {
      switch (status) {
        case "S":
          console.log("case s");
          card = "card-success";
          break;
        case "C":
        case "U":
        case "V":
          console.log("case cuv");
          card = "card-low";  // should display this one and works with variables defined within the function
          break;
        default:
          console.log("case default"); // display this one with data from function args
          card = "card-success";
          break;
      }
    }
    return card;
  }

getLevel('A','U');
getLevel('A','A');
getLevel('U','U');
```

Comment: No,  the real variable where status and validation, the other where only for test purpose

Comment: Your solution is not related to my issue: i never wanted do  test validation== status